# Interface query parameter parsing?

Tags: rest, jersey, jackson, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I believe this is not possible, but I just wanted to verify.

I would like to do something like...

```
@Path("/awesome")
public class MyRestResource {

  @GET
  public void coolQuery(@QueryParam("user") User) {
    // ...
  }
}

public interface User {
  String name();
  Address address();
}
```

(Please don't comment on the example... it's completely made-up and not my use case.)

I imagine this is not possible because Jersey/JAX-RS generally requires a static method `public static T valueOf(String input)` which obviously is not possible with interfaces.

That said, is there any work-around for this to have a query parameter be an interface?  And if so, how do you specify the parser / parsing logic?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e1883) there are more ways than just the static `valueOf` method:

> 1. Be a primitive type;
> 2. Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument;
> 3. Have a static method named `valueOf` or `fromString` that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, `Integer.valueOf(String)` and `java.util.UUID.fromString(String)`);
> 4. Have a registered implementation of `javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider` JAX-RS extension SPI that returns a `javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverter` instance capable of a "from string" conversion for the type. or
> 5. Be `List<T>`, `Set<T>` or `SortedSet<T>`, where `T` satisfies 2 or 3 above. The resulting collection is read-only.

The solution using a `ParamConverterProvider` should work in this case.

Comment: Missed the `ParamConverterProvider`. Never seen it used either, but works like a charm.

Comment: @Ryan that is because it was defined in JAX-RS 2.0 (released May 2013) and most of the people still use JAX-RS 1.0 (no matter the implementation).